# Litmit the length of the Id in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to limit the length of the ID column, mapped with Fluent NHibernate. I tried using `Id(u => u.UserId).Length(15)` but did not accomplish what I was going for - the *DATA_TYPE* column still showed `NUMBER(20,0)`. DB is Oracle, but I suppose it is the same for other DBs as well. `UserId` is of type long.

I know I can create a custom column, but, is there a built-in way to handle this?

Comment: The only way I know of is, creating custom user type that you can apply to given colums...

Answer (score 0):

Length is for strings. For numbers, it's called precision and scale. There is also a method to give the type directly.